What is the highest DPS tree path for the fire staff?
With the addition of gear slots allowing you to change all of your gear with the click of one button, I've been starting to play around with the fire staff lately. I have to say that raining fire down on enemies has been a lot of fun, haha.
I want to start running dungeons, which brings me to my question - what's the highest DPS tree path for the fire staff?
